# Python socket error : connexion refused (stack.error errno 111)

Tags: python, sockets

I have a code in python to communicate between two virtuals machines.

But I have an error. Connexion refused. are there any problems with the port that I use?
I don't think there is any firewall or anything.
thanks a lot

Here is my code below :

```
import socket
import subprocess

try:
    # on cree un objet socket
    # socket.AF_INET : la famille d adresses, ici ce sont des adresses Internet ;
    # socket.SOCK_STREAM : le type du socket, SOCK_STREAM pour le protocole TCP.

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # on defini le port
    port = 12345

    # connection vers le serveur
    s.connect(('192.168.1.20', port))

    # receive data from the server, 2048 bytes
    print s.recv(2048)

    # close the connection
    s.close()

except:
    print("une erreur est survenue...")
```

and then the code of my other machine

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os,sys
#==========================================================================================

#creation d'une classe pour rendre le programme oriente objet
class GetInfo:
    infos = os.uname()
    currentUser = os.getlogin()
    rep_actuel = os.getcwd()
    myDirectory = os.listdir("/home/debian/Documents")
    scanpath = "Liste de tous les repertoires dans Users : \n"

    def listInfo(self):
        #afficher des informations sur le systeme
        return GetInfo.infos
        #afficher l'utilisateur actuel
        return GetInfo.currentUser
        #afficher le path du repertoire actuel
        return GetInfo.rep_actuel

    def scan(self):
        #print "Liste de tous les repertoires dans Users/"
        #on liste toutes les directories et sous directories
        for file in GetInfo.myDirectory:
            GetInfo.scanpath += file + "; \n"
        return GetInfo.scanpath

#instance de l objet GetInfo (creation de l'objet)
GetMyInfo = GetInfo()
# afficage des infos de l'objet
#GetMyInfo.listInfo()
#GetMyInfo.scan()
#==========================================================================================
# on cree un objet socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket successfully created"

# reservation d'un port specifique
port = 12345

# contient le nom d hote et le numero du port
#identifiant le serveur auquel on veut se connecter.
s.bind(('192.168.1.15', port))
print "socket binded to %s" %(port)

# activation du mode ecoute
# avec un nombre maximum de connexions qu il peut recevoir sur ce port sans les accepter
s.listen(5)
print "socket is listening"


GetMyInfo.scan()

#==========================================================================================

# gestion des erreurs
while True:
   # on etabli la connection avec le client
   client, addr = s.accept()
   print 'Got connection from', addr

   #client.send("Liste de tous les repertoires dans Users/")
   # send the informations about the victim.
   client.send(GetMyInfo.scan())

   print client.recvfrom(2048)

# on ferme la connection
s.close()
```

the error says `Connexion refused` here is the error below
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1C1Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are connecting the client to one address:

```
# connection vers le serveur
s.connect(('192.168.1.20', port))  # <-- **.20**
```

But the server is listening on another:

```
# contient le nom d hote et le numero du port
#identifiant le serveur auquel on veut se connecter.
s.bind(('192.168.1.15', port))  # <-- **.15**
```